# what does XACML Identifier mean?

Tags: java, xml, xacml, xacml2

for example,"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:session-start-time",what does it mean?
How can i know the format of the session-start-time?
Is it yyyy-MM-dd or yyyy/MM/dd?
I can't find any Information form the oasis's document.SomeOne tell please,thx.

Answer (score 3):

The session-start-time attribute would represent when the session for the user identified in subject-id started.  This is likely when the user authenticated, I guess.

While the spec doesn't explicitly say what DataType the attribute is, I would assume that it's the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime` type.

You can find the definition of this type here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime; an example being "2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00"